# Prevent click on the html element according to the variable value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, onclick

I have this clickable `div` in a component which fires a todo function when the `div` is clicked:

```html
<div @click="todo()"></div>
```

Also, I have a global variable in the component which is called `price`.

I need to make the `div` above clickable, or the todo function firable only if the price value is greater than 100.

How can I achieve this behavior in Vue?

Comment: Does the `todo()` function have access to the global variable `price`? maybe try ```<div @click=`${price > 100 ? 'todo()' : ''}`></div>``` I have no experience with vue by the way....

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can simply write a wrapper function like so:

```html
<template>
  <div @click="onClick"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  data() {
    return {
      price: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isTodoCallAllowed() {
      return this.price > 100;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      if(this.isTodoCallAllowed) {
        this.todo();
      }
    },
    todo() {
      //
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, making `div`s clickable is usually bad practice, since it can make your interface really unclear and confusing to users.

With this in mind, I think it's easier if you replace your `div` with a `button` element, since `button`s allow you to use the `disabled` property to prevent clicks:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      price: 100
    }
  },
  computed: {
    priceIsOver() {
      return this.price > 100;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    todo() {
      console.log('doing stuff');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    Price: {{price}} <button @click="price++">+</button> <button @click="price--">-</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button :disabled="!priceIsOver" @click="todo">TODO</button>
</div>
```